# Casualty lists in school newspaper in Alice Winn's In Memoriam

Tags: alice-winn, in-memoriam-alice-winn

Alice Winn's *In Memoriam* (2023) is set in part at Preshute, a fictional public school, around the time of World War I. The school newspaper carries a roll of honour that lists the names of deceased, injured, or missing alumni. Some of these old boys had run away from school to enlist despite being too young. They had lied to the recruiting officer, claiming to be nineteen.

This newspaper seems to be a sought-after source of information:

> On the 30th April, there was a scrum at the door of Fletcher Hall.
>      "What's going on?" Elwood asked Pritchard.
>      "Apparently there's been another battle at Ypres. Everyone's trying to get hold of *The Preshutian* to see the casualty lists."

One of the entries on the casualty lists reads:

> Ward, Sec.-Lieut, S. A., Duke of Cornwall's Light Infantry.
> Killed in action near Ypres on April 23rd, aged 17.

I have three questions about this. First, many with brothers at the front apprehensively scan the casualty lists. But why would a student need to look through the casualty lists to find out whether or not his brother is on there? One would expect that on receiving word of the death, the student's family would send a telegram to the school. Or was it the case that casualty lists published in newspapers were in fact the first communication of death, since official letters from the deceased's commanding officer would not reach the family until later? Even so, the school newspaper would be a weekly at most, and one imagines daily newspapers would carry the casualty lists. Even if the students had no access to daily newspapers, their teachers and families would, and this again raises the issue of why students would need to look at the school newspaper for this information.

Second, it is established that the the editors of the school newspaper are students, not staff. How would they know which of the people on the casualty lists were old boys? Even assuming the military kept records of the educational background of its recruits, it seems unlikely that it would send custom lists to public schools. And if the editors do some cross-checking to identify past students, then it seems callous that they would withhold information about a dead or injured brother from a student until publication, rather than asking a teacher to break the news to the student privately.

Third, since those who enlisted underage would have lied about how old they were, how would the casualty lists have their actual age rather than the made-up one? Wouldn't Ward's age have been recorded as nineteen, not seventeen? Or is this supposed to be another intervention by the school newspaper editors?

I will split these into separate questions if that seems indicated, but the answer to all might very well be the same: that Winn isn't being scrupulous in her historical reconstruction, and that the reader should suspend disbelief and roll with it.

Comment: You might like to look at "Good-bye, Mr. Chips" (https://www.fadedpage.com/books/20170484/html.php), which describes life at a minor public school during the 1914-18 war.  As the author was at such a school at the time, his description presumably reflects what might have happened.